# Why did Haru put her arm into Legoshi's mouth in episode 11?

Tags: beastars

In the episode 11 of Beastars, Haru (the rabbit girl) put her arm into Legoshi's (the wolf boy) mouth in the hotel when they were going to have [...] and the explanation was that it was her instinct as a herbivore to do so. But as far as goes my knowledge, animals mostly tend to flee when they are in danger or any other unconfortable situation and do not try to be eaten.

Was that explanation right or maybe it is a mistranslation of the fansub? It's the same in the manga? If yes, is that behavior right according to the reallity or did the author make up that? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr at bottom

As a heads up I have not read the Manga so take my answer as what you will.

Through out the majority of the season we've seen Legoshi come to terms about how he feels about Haru and how his mind and body conflict at times. Legoshi went from Haru is food, Haru is not food, Love Haru, Haru is prey, essentially figuring whether he felt the way he did because he either liked her or wanted to eat her. He however reached his conclusion that he liked her.

Haru I would say has not yet gone through all this development and is either only just starting to or is in the midst of it. She has only really accepted that somebody likes her for herself without pitying her and just thought that that is enough, when reality her body is screaming that something terriby wrong.

Conclusion, while I don't necessarily believe that the action of putting her arm in his mouth is intrinsically a defensive mechanism, its more of a manifestation of the conflict that she has yet to/currently going though.

Tl;Dr:
Body: want to run,
Mind: I like him though,
Body: PANIC DO SOMETHING WERE GONNA BE Eaten,
Mind: hells ye we are ;),
Body: SMURGAFLEEEUR ARM TAKE, THEN LEEEAVE

Comment: I would add that it was probably part of her fight/flight/freeze (sympathetic nervous system) response. When this happened, I assumed it was a response that her instincts thought would keep her alive: although she would lose her arm, it would distract the predator long enough to allow her to escape and live another day. However, due to the context of the situation she was in, made it incredibly awkward and hard to understand.